# Ковариантность и контрвариантность делегатов

Tags: c#, классы

Господа, по Шилдту прочитал о ковариантности и контрвариантности делегатов. И насколько я понял, то это совместимость аргументов или возвращаемых типов между базовыми и производными классами. Для примера решил написать простенький код. Но, исходя из того, что я понял, получается, что он не работает. Почему?

`

```
 using System;
class a
{
    public a Meth()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1); return new a();
    }
}
class b : a
{
    public new b Meth()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1); return new b();
    }
}
public delegate a Del();
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Del D = new b().Meth;
        D();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Выдает такую вот ошибку:

Ошибка 1    Несовместимость по доступности: доступность типа возвращаемого значения "a" ниже доступности делегата "Del"

Comment: Эта ошибка не имеет отношения к вариативности делегатов. У вас просто делегат публичный, а тип возвращаемого им значения имеет модификатор internal

Comment: !!! Вообще взрыв мозга. А не могли бы вы, если не затруднит, привести очень простой пример ковариантности и контрвариантности. А то я теперь вообще не пойму ничего. Спасибо.
_____

Но ведь internal дает доступ внутри сборки - значит он должен быть виден. Или я что-то путаю?
_____

Убрал модификатор public у Del, и заработал! Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного подробнее о причинах ошибки. Итак, ошибка  том, что у вашего делегата стоит модификатор public, тогда как у типа, являющегося возвращаемым значением этого делегата, модификатор internal (явно не указан, но стоит по умолчанию).

Вы спрашиваете:

> Но ведь internal дает доступ внитри сборки - значит он должен быть виден

но ведь использовать этот делегат вы можете не только внутри сборки (на то он и public), однако, используя его в другой сборке, вы не смогли бы обратиться к его возвращаемому значению, поскольку из других сборок оно не может быть видимым. Собственно, добавив public для классов a и b, вы решите эту проблему. Точно так же вы решите ее, сделав ваш делегат internal - в таком случае отпадет проблема использования возвращаемого значения из других сборок.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.